# Retrofit2 Android. Не получается вернуть информацию полученную от сервера

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Здравствуйте!

Прошу помочь разобраться новичку в Retrofit.

Суть: С помощью Retrofit2 делаю запрос на сервер. От сервера успешно приходит ответ, который никак не получается "вытащить" из внутреннего класса для дальнейшей работы с ним.

Более конкретно фрагмент кода:

```
    public List<String[]> getHouse(Call<RespHomes> req) {

     final LinkedList<String[]> homesInfo = new LinkedList<>();
     //делаем запрос
     req.enqueue(new Callback<RespHomes>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RespHomes> call, Response<RespHomes> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                List<String> members = response.body().getSwornMembers();
                if (members.size() > 0) {
                    //если количество членов дома больше нуля
                    String nameOfHome = response.body().getName();
                    for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
                        String[] about = new String[2];
                        //название дома
                        about[0] = nameOfHome;
                        //ссылка на члена дома
                        about[1] = members.get(i);

                        homesInfo.add(about);
                        //проверка какие именно данные получены
                        Log.d("TAG","Request: " + homesInfo.get(i)[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RespHomes> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG","Ошибка подключения к сервису!");
        }
    });
    return homesInfo;
}
```

Внутри функции onResponce данные корректно приходят от сервера и записываются в homesInfo. Однако, по факту в строке

> return homesInfo;

возвращается все-равно пустая коллекция. Пробовал добиться результата с помощью Handler-а, сохранением во внутренние переменные класса, через паттерн Memento. Результат нулевой. Очень прошу помочь с вопросом. Заранее спасибо!
П.С. Прошу строго не судить, только начал работать с Retrofit.

Comment: А Вы понимаете почему так происходит?

Comment: А попробуйте перед return вывести в лог какой-нибудь homesInfo.get(0)[1]. И сразу после получения из функции списка выведите это значение.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, Пусто там будет. Запрос асинхронный. Метод возвращает значение раньше чем приходит результат.

Comment: Да. Там пусто. Ошибка: IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: post_zeew, если проблема в асинхронности, то как мне избежать этой ошибки? Делать какой-нибудь observer, который будет оповещать, что данные получены или как?

Comment: А, точно. Я делал через HttpClient в AsyncTask. Там с этим понятнее.

Comment: Вам надо передавать homesInfo ИЗ метода onResponse

Answer (score 1):

Следите за руками

```
//тут у вас создается пустой экземпляр LinkedList
final LinkedList<String[]> homesInfo = new LinkedList<>();

//тут вы запускаете асинхронный запрос
req.enqueue(new Callback<RespHomes>() {
...

//тут вы возвращаете созданный выше пустой экземпляр LinkedList, в то время, как
//запрос все еще отрабатывает в соседнем потоке
return homesInfo;
```

Получение и дальнейшее использование результата запроса происходит в методе

```
public void onResponse(Call<RespHomes> call, Response<RespHomes> response) {
```

Вставляйте в него необходимую вам логику работы с результатом запроса

Answer (score 1):

Ваш метод возвращает пустой `LinkedList<String[]>`, так как во время выполнения `return homesInfo;` запрос, по результатам которого заполняется список, еще не выполнился.

При использовании *асинхронных* запросов создается новый поток, а результат запроса возвращается в коллбэк `onResponse(...)` (в случае успешного выполнения) и в `onFailure(...)` (в случае возникновения ошибки).

Таким образом, `поток A`, в котором выполняется метод `getHouse(...)` запускает `Поток B`, в котором происходит выполнение запроса. `Поток A`, который запустил выполнение запроса, работает параллельно с `Потоком B`, в котором выполняется запрос. В итоге получается так, что заполнение списка по результатам запроса происходит **позже** завершения работы метода `getHouse(...)`.

Если Вам нужно чтобы именно этот метод вернул результат запроса, то, например, можно использовать *синхронные* запросы (но в этом случае придется вручную создавать новый поток и запускать метод в нем, так как работать с сетью из UI-потока нельзя).

Comment: Ок. Мне в общем-то стало ясно. Спасибо за ответы. Они были полезны для меня.